# Flip effect between images

Tags: android, flip

I'm developing an eBook Reader and need to have the flip effect between pages.

I want has support to flip from right or left.

How can I do that on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solve my problem:

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

This doesn't have the effect of the reflected image but help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

For basic page-turning animations, the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) and [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) classes -- they can apply any inAnimation and outAnimation you can define in a resource file.

However, for full effect you'll want the curved page bulging toward you as it passes by, which I think is beyond the ability of those simple animations (somebody correct me if that's wrong), and you'll want a touch event handler so it happens through the whole dragging motion.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this View : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html